# MS Excel percentage of change function

Tags: microsoft-excel

Does Excel have a built-in percentage of change function like `(A1-B1)/B1 %`? I seem can't find it in built-in function list.

Example:
A1=1.0123
B1=1.0
I want to get the ratio (1.0123-1.0)/1.0 % = 1.23%

Comment: Do you want a decimal, or do you want something like 3:1 as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UDF that will have the same behavior and return a string with the percent tacked onto the end:

```
Function Ratio(ByVal val1 As Range, ByVal val2 As Range) As String
    rat = (val1 - val2) / val2
    rat = rat * 100

    Ratio = Format(rat, "Fixed") & "%"
End Function
```

Comment: By definition a UDF isn't a built in function .....

Comment: @brettdj I agree, but I was offering an alternative to the OP.

Comment: fair enough. Although returning a string probably isn't the most optimal form for a numeric calc

Answer (score 2):

No

You would simply enter in a formula as you have and then format it as a percentage